# For f continuous on $[0,1]$, show that there exist points $\alpha_k$ such that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{f'(\alpha_k)} = n $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Suppose that $f$ is continous on $[0,1]$ , differentiable on $(0,1)$ , and $f(0)=0$ and  $f(1)=1$.For every integer $n$ show  that there must exist $n$ distinct points $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\cdots,\alpha_n$ in that interval so that
>    $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{f'(\alpha_k)} = n $

Is it theorem or i can show it with basic differentiation knowledge .Please give me hint .

Comment: Hint: A twist of [MVT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) - given any two numbers $a,b$ such that $0 \le a < b \le 1$ and $f(b) \ne f(a)$, there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{f'(c)} = b - a$.

Comment: Hint: Use the mean value theorem repeatedly. First to get the existence of a point $\xi$ such that $f'(\xi)=1$. Then pair points $a$ and $b$ (again using the mean value theorem and the intermediate value property of derivatives) such that $1/f'(a)+1/f'(b)=2$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$f$ is *continuous* with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. It follows from the
[intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) that there are numbers
$$
   0 = b_0 < b_1 < \dots < b_{n-1} < b_n = 1
$$
such that 
$$
  f(b_j) = \frac jn \text{ for } j= 0, \ldots, n \quad .
$$

Now use the fact that $f$ is *differentiable* and apply the
[mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)
to each interval $[b_{j-1}, b_j]$, $j = 1, \ldots n$.
It follows that there are numbers $\alpha_j \in (b_{j-1}, b_j)$ such that
$$
   f'(\alpha_j) = \frac{f(b_j) - f(b_{j-1})}{b_j - b_{j-1}} = \frac 1{n(b_j - b_{j-1})} \quad .
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac 1{f'(\alpha_j)} = n \sum_{j=1}^n (b_j - b_{j-1}) = n(b_n - b_0) = n
\quad .
$$
The $\alpha_j$ are necessarily distinct because they are in distinct
intervals $(b_{j-1}, b_j)$.